# Is there a way to force hibernate to update mapped sets within an entity?

Tags: database, hibernate

I have the following mapped in my entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="categoryScheme")
private Set<RolePlayerCategorySchemeRel> rolePlayerCategorySchemeRelationshipsAsSet = new HashSet<RolePlayerCategorySchemeRel>();
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentCategoryScheme")
private Set<CategoryScheme> childCategorySchemesAsSet = new HashSet<CategoryScheme>();
```

The sets are children of the entity based on IDs.  I am changing the ID of this entity, which should make the child sets change, but they're not.  It's because Hibernate isn't for some reason going back out to the database and updating the sets.

So, the question is:  Is there a way to force Hibernate to update/refresh these sets from the database?

Thanks,
Dale

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. What do you mean by "I am changing the ID of this entity"? If you mean that you're trying to change the value of its primary key, then whatever you try won't work. This is illegal. An ID is immutable and can't be changed. The only thing you can do is delete the entity and recreate it with another ID.

Comment: @JB Nizet I'm only now understanding my problem enough to explain it well.  Here's another shot.  I've got an entity with collections in it as seen mapped in the orinal post.  I am changing something in the collections.  When I retrieve this entity, hibernate is not refreshing the collection so I'm looking at stale data.  How do I force hibernate (using JPA/Hibernate) to refresh the collection from the database?  Are the collections being cached somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: If you're doing the "change in the collection" and the "retrieving of the entity" in the same transaction, then Hibernate returns the entity from its first-level cache. It's your responsibility to maintain both sides of a bidirectional association.

Comment: As far as I know, I'm not doing it in the same transaction.  Say dogs is a set of animal.  I'm changing a dog doing merge() then flush() (also tried clear() after the flush) on the dog then retrieving animals from the DB and the dogs set comes back as stale data.  So, am I doing this in the same transaction?

Comment: when I get to work, I can post some code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem & came here looking for an answer, but didn't find one.

HOWEVER, I did finally solve my problem.  I had the 'inverse' parameter of my Set mapping set to 'true', and the behavior was similar to what you were describing above;  changing it to 'false' corrected the problem.  From what I was able to see in one of the manuals, the side of the relationship where inverse is false ends up controlling the update behavior.

Hope this helps you.